# How to get the Socket Buffer size in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a Socket code which is communicating through TCP/IP.The machine to which i am communicating has buffer data in its buffer.At present i am trying to get the buffer data using this code.

```
byte data = new byte[1024];
int recv = sock.Receive(data);   
stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
```

But this code retrieves only 11 lines of data whereas more data is there in the machines  buffer.Is this because i have used `int recv = sock.Receive(data);` and data is `1024` ?
If yes ,How to get the total buffer size and retrieve it into string.

Comment: "whereas more data is there in the machines buffer": how do you know this?

Comment: you just asked to read 1024 bytes from socket. You may need to loop till it returns no data (0 bytes).

Comment: If the 11 lines are 1024 bytes in total it would make sense.

Comment: @bansi how to recieve all data at a time?

Comment: @Ram, bansi literally told you in the comment. Read it again.

Comment: @Richard I have checked buffer in the Hyperterminal

Comment: @bansi I dont want to while loop i want to get all at a time?

Comment: "checked buffer in the Hyperterminal": this won't help. If sending the buffering on send and receive end will likely be different. If as a test receive: there is no guarantee the same sequence of sends will be received the same (eg. different packet fragmentation over different route).

Comment: I don't know of any other option with sockets. there is no guarantee you can get all data in a single read even if you allocate huge buffer

Comment: @bansi indeed, it is exceptionally unlikely that you would get all the data in a single read; for this reason, a receive buffer does not usually need to be very large.

Comment: @Ram You can wait a long time and then call `recv` and you're more likely to get all the data at once, if it fits in the receive buffer. But why find some ugly horrible way when calling `recv` in a loop is simple and logical?

Answer (score 8):

If you think you are missing some data, then you need to check `recv` and almost certainly: loop. Fortunately, `ASCII` is always single byte - in most other encodings you would also have to worry about receiving partial characters.

A common approach is basically:

```
int recv;
while((recv = sock.Receive(data)) > 0)
{
    // process recv-many bytes
    // ... stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
}
```

Keep in mind that there is no guarantee that `stringData` will be any particular entire unit of work; what you send is not always what you receive, and that could be a single character, 14 lines, or the second half of one word and the first half of another. You generally need to maintain your own back-buffer of received data until you have a complete logical frame to process.

Note, however, `Receive` always tries to return *something* (at least one byte), unless the inbound stream has closed - and will block to do so. If this is a problem, you may need to check the available buffer (`sock.Available`) to decide whether to do synchronous versus asynchronous receive (i.e. read synchronously while data is available, otherwise request an asynchronous read).

Comment: @bansi let's just say that I do "quite a lot" of socket work ;p

Comment: I gave you +1 anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Console.WriteLine(" ReceiveBufferSize {0}", tcpSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

For actual data you can put below condition:-

```
int receiveBytes;
while((receiveBytes = tcpSocket.Receive.Data(receiveBytes)) > 0)
{
}
```

Comment: `ReceiveBufferSize` is not the size of data in buffer. it is the buffer size allocated by windows for the socket

Comment: as documented in msdn website : "Gets or sets a value that specifies the size of the receive buffer of the Socket."

Comment: @bansi Note what the Q asked: this directly answers the question. (Of course the questioner is not really sure what they are asking because they appear to be making significant assumptions about the way sockets (and networks in general) send data.)

Comment: @Neel exactly. not the size of actual data. which can be more or less.

Comment: I have answered what I understood from question..yes agree with you @Richard

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
StringBuilder sbContent=new StringBuilder();
byte data = new byte[1024];
int numBytes;

while ((numBytes = sock.Receive(data))>0)
{
  sbContent.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
}

// use sbContent.ToString()
```